# SSIS C# Script Task Error

Tags: c#, ssis

All, I'm using SQL 2014 and Visual Studio 2013.

I have a script task that is not firing.  It's being read, but not working.  This task creates tables and inserts data into them.  I need to do this with a script task as there are 100's of TSV files and the fields may change month to month and it's a pain maintaining individual nodes for each table.

If you look at the code snippet, the message boxes (1) do fire, but the script errors right after - I believe at (2):

[image]

The error message is:

[image]

I think this error refers to variables that are not accessible in the task or are misspelled, etc.  I've checked these Ad nauseam - don't think that's it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Should I rephrase this question?  Any suggestions at all??

Comment: Could the issue be that I have an oledb connection AND a ADO connection happening at the same time?  Could one step on the other?

Comment: Several comments
Your error tells about missing element in collection, and looks like it occurs in accessing variable. If you comment out all references to variables, will the exception still fire? Try to set a breakpoint at the first line of script task and step it untill it crashes to identify the place.
Your connection manager `DBconn` - is it ADO.NET or OLEDB?

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The connection is OLE DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are creating an ADO.NET (C# standard) connection in your script code, but the **base** of this - `DBconn` connection manager - is an OLEDB connection manager. These two connections could not be casted into one another.

Suggestions:

- If possible, create `DBconn` connection manager as an ADO.NET. Then your code should work.
- In case you have to keep `DBconn` as an OLEDB connection manager, you have to create a `SqlConnection` connection in script task based on `DBconn`. I have done that building connection string for ADO.NET from OLEDB conn string and creating a new `SqlConnection` with that connection string.

Below is a code sample for function generating Connection String.

```
using RuntimeWrapper = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

static string Get_ManagedConnString(string Src_Name, ConnectionManager CM)
    {
    if (CM.CreationName != "OLEDB")
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot get Conn String from non-OLEDB Conn manager {0}", CM.Name));

    RuntimeWrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams_Src = CM.InnerObject as RuntimeWrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
    OleDbConnection oledbConn_Src = cmParams_Src.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder oledbCSBuilder_Src = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(oledbConn_Src.ConnectionString);
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlCSBuilder_Src = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlCSBuilder_Src.DataSource = oledbCSBuilder_Src["Data Source"].ToString();
    sqlCSBuilder_Src.InitialCatalog = oledbCSBuilder_Src["Initial Catalog"].ToString();
    if (oledbCSBuilder_Src["integrated security"].ToString() == "SSPI")
        {
        sqlCSBuilder_Src.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        }
    else
        {
        sqlCSBuilder_Src.UserID = oledbCSBuilder_Src["User ID"].ToString();
        sqlCSBuilder_Src.Password = oledbCSBuilder_Src["Password"].ToString();
        }

    return sqlCSBuilder_Src.ConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and workaround.  This will suffice - Curious, would a third solution be to create another ADO connection and refer to that new connection in the C# script above (swap out DBconn with ,say, DBconnADO?

Comment: @Craig, certainly, it will do the trick. For a 1-time package its Ok, but for long-time support - not; maintenance of such things in production could break upon time. That is why I prefer to define 1 Connection Manager for 1 source, and derive from that.